# Infowindow selection change

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using infowindow to display the results of identifyTask that has two layers from my map service so it returns multiple features.
The infowindow has more button in each feature it identifies so that when I click the more button I get the data of current feature. How can I get the current selected feature? I am using this [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/find_popup.html).
 I want to get incase the popup identifies more than one feature to get current feature How can this be done.

Answer (score 2):

For the [map.infoWindow](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html), you can either access the entire list of selected graphics by working with [map.infoWindow.features](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#features), or you can get the current selected feature using [map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature()](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#getselectedfeature). This returns a graphic, and you can get the data on that graphic by looking at graphic.attributes.

```
function getMoreInfo() {
  var graphic = map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature();

  // do something with the data inside the graphic
  doSomething(graphic.attributes);
}
```

If you want to know when the selected feature is changed in the infoWindow, and you're using an API version 3.4 or later (when the Popup was made the default infoWindow), you'll need to set up a listener to the infoWindow's ["selection-change"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#event-selection-change) event. Here's how you could do it using [dojo/on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html).

```
dojoOn(map.infoWindow, "selection-change", getMoreInfo);
```

Comment: How do you know when the user has clicked the arrow to select a different feature?  InfoWindow appears to only have show/hide events.

Comment: If you're you're using the Popup InfoWindow, which was made default back in v3.4, you can listen to the infoWindow's "selection-change" event. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#event-selection-change. I'll update my answer

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely correct.  I'm using a webmap from ArcGIS Online and had not made the mental connection that map.infoWindow is an instance of PopUp. I was just looking at the docs for esri.dijit.InfoWindow wondering why there wasn't a whole lot there.  I tested "selection-change" in this case and it worked.  Thanks!